# How to query ManyToMany through relationship with some property in django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

```
class Person(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Group(models.Model):
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person,through=Membership)

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    existing = models.BooleanField()
```

This is the simplified class structure and what I want to query is:
A queryset on group such that there are some people with membership such that `existing` is true.
I have tried using `Group.objects.filter(membership__existing=True)` but it seems to be grabbing all the Groups.

What is the most efficient way to filter out the queryset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a sample app using your model definitions, and the filter you've specified works fine. I had to change the `through` attribute of the `people` field to be a string, as `Membership` isn't defined yet. I also added a name field to `Group` to make it easier to test.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    existing = models.BooleanField()
```

Then in the console:

```
>>> p1 = Person.objects.create(age=10)
>>> p2 = Person.objects.create(age=20)
>>> has_existing = Group.objects.create(name='has_existing')
>>> has_non_existing = Group.objects.create(name='has_non_existing')
>>> has_none = Group.objects.create(name='has_none')
>>> Membership.objects.create(person=p1, group=has_existing, existing=True)
>>> Membership.objects.create(person=p2, group=has_non_existing, existing=False)
>>> existing = Group.objects.filter(membership__existing=True)
>>> assert(len(existing) == 1)
>>> assert(existing[0].name == 'has_existing')
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have tested again and noticed that my real code is using a `NullBooleanField` and the condition I want is it is null. So I used `filter(membership__existing__isnull=True)` which will also include those without any membership. Works fine after changing to `filter(membership__isnull=False,membership__existing__isnull=True)`